# Splitting a title into separate parts

Tags: regex

I need a to split a string of the form

`2,9.1,The Godfather (1972)`, (it's a csv line)

to:

```
2
9.1
The Godfather
1972
```

any ideas for a good regular expression?

BTW,
if you know a good regular expressions creator based on examples you provide it'd be great.
I'm a bit new to this..

10x!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using regex to split the csv files as it can't handle comma escaping well. But having that said, how about using the simplest available solution?

A simplest regex like this should solve your problem

```
'(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)\((\d+)\)'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(\d+)\.(\d+\.\d+),(.*?)(?= \()\((\d{4})\)
^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
2      9.1        Title        Year
```

Answer (score 0):

A little time with Google gave me this: **`/,(?!(?:[^",]|[^"],[^"])+")/`**. Seeems to split CSV just fine.

```
>>> '2,9.1,The Godfather (1972)'.split(/,(?!(?:[^",]|[^"],[^"])+")/)
["2", "9.1", "The Godfather (1972)"]
```

Comment: He wanted "The Godfather" and "1972" to be separate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the format is static, you can use this:

```
(\d+),(\d+\.\d+),(.*?) \((\d+)\)
```

But if it can contain more information, use a real CSV parser to read the line and then just split `The Godfather (1972)` using `(.*?) \((\d+)\)`.

Answer (score 0):

CSV has a lot of corner cases, your regexp approach might take you into a world of pain.

For example if the title has a comma in it, the title would then be double quoted. Which would screw up with all of the regexps given so far.